# Common install paths for PHP on Windows

Tags: php

I'm building a setup process that needs to know where PHP (php-win.exe) is installed on Windows. It asks the user for the location, but ideally it will test a few obvious locations first.

Obvious install paths include:

- C:/Program Files/PHP
- C:/wamp/bin/php/version/

Does anyone have either a list or more suggestions?

[this is being used by a command line tool as opposed to an installer which would make it easy just to select the folder].

Answer (score 2):

The most common path I've seen for PHP on Windows is:

> C:\php

If you're checking for `wamp` you could also check for `xampp`.

Answer (score 0):

Install the top 4 or 5 [WAMPs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WAMPs) to see where they place PHP.

Most of them place it with-in their own folder.

For example, Wamp-Developer places PHP into C:\WampDeveloper\Components\Php

That, in addition to the standalone folders for PHP, should cover 95% of it.

Your setup process could also run a quick directory search for php.exe.